# Rotation on extension-field

Tags: linear-algebra, extension-field

I have corrected the question in the following.

---

For $x_1$ and $x_2$ real vectors which span $V=\mathbb{R}x_1\oplus \mathbb{R} x_2$.
we have a rotation $R$ on $V$ given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
R\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, consider $V^\mathbb C=\mathbb C\otimes_\mathbb{R}V=V\oplus iV$, it is $2$-dimensional $C$-vector space.

The question is:

How to choose a $\mathbb C$-basis such that $R$ acts on $V^\mathbb C$
as
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\theta}&\\
&e^{-i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column of $A$ must be a non-zero member of the kernel of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
} - e^{i\theta}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} =
\pmatrix{
\frac{1}{2}\left(-e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}\right) & \sin \theta\\
-\sin \theta & \frac{1}{2}\left(-e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}\right)
}\\
= \pmatrix{
i\sin \theta & \sin \theta\\
-\sin \theta & i\sin \theta
}
$$
Similarly, the second column of $A$ must be a non-zero member of the kernel of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
} - e^{-i\theta}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} =
\pmatrix{
-i\sin \theta & \sin \theta\\
-\sin \theta & -i\sin \theta
}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake in the question above. I have corrected it.

Comment: You haven't changed the question very much.  The only difference is that instead of finding the columns of $A$, you are finding the vectors in your basis.  At any rate, the basis $$\pmatrix{\sin \theta \\ -i\sin \theta}, \pmatrix{\sin \theta\\ i \sin \theta}$$ is satisfactory.  That is, you could simply take the basis $$\pmatrix{1 \\ -i}, \pmatrix{1\\ i}$$

Comment: I understand, thanks a lot!